# How to make a page transition with Framer Motion and Next.js 14?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion, react-server-components

I'm trying to make a page transition with Next.js v14 but no success.

No error is shown, the animation just does't work. I guess it's because the `layout.tsx` is rendered on the server. But how can I fix it?

My `layout.tsx` code (root level):

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Sidebar from "@/components/Sidebar";
import Breadcrumbs from "@/components/Breadcrumbs";
import Topbar from "@/components/Topbar";
import PageTransitionEffect from "@/components/PageTransitionEffect";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${inter.className} flex flex-col min-h-screen`}>
        <Topbar />

        <div className="bg-gray-800 text-gray-200 flex flex-grow overflow-x-hidden px-0">
          <Sidebar />

          <div className="flex-col mx-auto flex w-full py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-14">
            <Breadcrumbs />

            <PageTransitionEffect>{children}</PageTransitionEffect>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

My `PageTransitionEffect` component code:

```
"use client";

import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const PageTransitionEffect = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const variants = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0, x: -200, y: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1, x: 0, y: 0 },
    exit: { opacity: 0, x: 0, y: -100 },
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
      initial="hidden"
      animate="enter"
      exit="exit"
      variants={variants}
      transition={{ type: "linear" }}
    >
      {children}
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default PageTransitionEffect;
```

Edit #1 (warning message):

```
Warning: Detected multiple renderers concurrently rendering the same context provider. This is currently unsupported.
    at FrozenRouter (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./src/components/PageTransitionEffect/index.tsx:21:70)
    at div
    at MotionComponent (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/motion/index.mjs:49:65)
    at PopChildMeasure (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/PopChild.mjs:13:1)
    at PopChild (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/PopChild.mjs:33:21)
    at PresenceChild (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/PresenceChild.mjs:15:26)
    at AnimatePresence (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/index.mjs:72:28)
    at PageTransitionEffect (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./src/components/PageTransitionEffect/index.tsx:49:33)
    at div
    at div
    at body
    at html
    at RootLayout (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./src/app/layout.tsx:21:23)
    at Lazy
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:71:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:79:11)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:66:9)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:298:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:154:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:99:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:128:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:426:13)
    at Lazy
    at Lazy
    at C:\Projects\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:374733
    at C:\Projects\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:374733
    at ServerInsertedHTMLProvider (C:\Projects\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:38:23140)
```

The component code:

```
"use client";

import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { LayoutRouterContext } from "next/dist/shared/lib/app-router-context.shared-runtime";
import { useContext, useRef } from "react";

function FrozenRouter(props: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const context = useContext(LayoutRouterContext);
  const frozen = useRef(context).current;

  return (
    <LayoutRouterContext.Provider value={frozen}>
      {props.children}
    </LayoutRouterContext.Provider>
  );
}

const variants = {
  hidden: { opacity: 0, x: -30, y: 0 },
  enter: { opacity: 1, x: 0, y: 0 },
  exit: { opacity: 0, x: -30, y: 0 },
};

const PageTransitionEffect = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  // The `key` is tied to the url using the `usePathname` hook.
  const key = usePathname();

  return (
    <AnimatePresence mode="popLayout">
      <motion.div
        key={key}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="enter"
        exit="exit"
        variants={variants}
        transition={{ type: "linear", duration: 0.2, delay: 0.1 }}
      >
        <FrozenRouter>{children}</FrozenRouter>
      </motion.div>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

export default PageTransitionEffect;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is currently [a bug caused by the app router and shared layouts](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49279) that prevents this from working correctly. However, there is [a workaround](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49279#issuecomment-1674914893). Besides the workaround, there are 3 other things we need:

1. [`AnimatePresence`](https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/) from framer motion *(This helps us use exiting and entering animations)*
2. A `key` on the motion element to [trigger a re-render](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#resetting-state-with-a-key) *(This triggers the animation when the page changes)*
3. Add `mode='popLayout'` to `AnimatePresence` *(This removes the old page from the tree immediately. You can play around with the mode value, [different modes are better for some animations](https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/###mode).)*

Example:

```
"use client";

import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { LayoutRouterContext } from "next/dist/shared/lib/app- router-context.shared-runtime";
import { useContext, useRef } from "react";

function FrozenRouter(props: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const context = useContext(LayoutRouterContext ?? {});
  const frozen = useRef(context).current;

  return (
    <LayoutRouterContext.Provider value={frozen}>
      {props.children}
    </LayoutRouterContext.Provider>
  );
}

const variants = {
  hidden: { opacity: 0, x: -200, y: 100 },
  enter: { opacity: 1, x: 0, y: 0 },
  exit: { opacity: 0, x: 0, y: -100 },
};

const PageTransitionEffect = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  // The `key` is tied to the url using the `usePathname` hook.
  const key = usePathname();

  return (
    <AnimatePresence mode="popLayout">
      <motion.div
        key={key}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="enter"
        exit="exit"
        variants={variants}
        transition={{ type: "linear" }}
        className="overflow-hidden"
      >
        <FrozenRouter>{children}</FrozenRouter>
      </motion.div>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

export default PageTransitionEffect;
```

[Here is a working example.](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/page-transition-in-app-router-w-framer-motion-n2v2nr?file=%2Fapp%2FPageTransition.tsx%3A2%2C1)

Comment: That's working now! Thanks a milion! Is there any downside when doing it?

Comment: Although it's working, there's a warning message on console (only happens when refreshing the page, not while changing the routes on client side) ... please see edit #1

Comment: Hmmm, after playing around with it for a bit, I got this error: `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')`. It may need a refactor. I'll take a look and edit when I can.

Comment: @AlexandrePaiva I made a slight update to the code in the workaround. The thing about workarounds is they aren't guaranteed. We can do our best though .

Comment: Thanks man! I'll try it... The only difference is the classname?

Comment: unfortunately the issues persists... Did you manage to fix it in your working sample?

Comment: I've been messing around with the [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/page-transition-in-app-router-w-framer-motion-n2v2nr?file=%2Fapp%2FPageTransitionEffect.tsx) I posted in my answer. I'm unable to replicate the error that you're seeing though. I've been [reading about that error you're seeing](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/37424) and attempting to fix it, but it's tricky without being able to replicate it.

Comment: tanks, this worked for me